# Blender not allowing different effector collections for two different particles systems

Tags: particles

I have two different emitters with different particle systems. When I set an effector collection on one - it also changes it for the other. Any idea how to control these independently? I am using the molecular addon.

Here is the project: [image]

Thanks!

[image][image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the same particle settings in the two particle systems on your emitters. You have a different name in the particle system slot, but it's not a different setting.

Think of the particle system slot to be more like a material slot. You can put more materials on one object, but as long as the material in one slot is the same as one on a different object, changing one material will change the other, too.

In the materials this is indicated by a small number next to the material's name. The same goes for the particle settings shown below the particle system slots. And like in materials, to get a new independent particle setting, just click on the small number right next to it.

[image: particle settings]

Comment: Confusingly, particle system slots can have names, where material slots display the name of the materials assigned to them.

Comment: Yeah I know.. but once you know that it's not a big problem. Maybe you want to name a particle system in a slot according to what it's used for on that special object while still share properties with particle systems on other objects. There are some independent settings, for example the seed value. If you want to have two objects where the particles have the same properties but don't want the animation to look exactly the same on both objects, you change the seed on one of them. Or hair: you can have two objects have the same hair settings, but different particle edits.

Comment: Here's not enough room for text... especially using hair particles this becomes quite handy: Say you have a single object but want different parts have hair of different quality. Make one slot e.g. "head" and the second slot "beard" but take the same particle system setings for both. You can comb, cut etc. them differently... the settings can even have different dynamics, for example one with a stiffness of 0.2, the other 0.8 or maybe even one deactivated dynamics, the other activated. Now if you want to change hair thickness, number of children etc. you can do it for both at the same time.